# Arbitrary spatial autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial

A spatial autoregressive model includes a *spatial lag* of the dependent variable.

$$ y = \rho W y + x\beta$$

Where $W$ describes the spatial relationship between elements of the model. I have heard (from reputable sources) that OLS estimations of this model are inconsistent, and so `spdep::lagsarlm` for R, for instance, uses eigenvalue decomposition or generalized method of moments to estimate $\rho$ and $\beta$.

But suppose I want to estimate a model to test whether an attribute $x_1$ of the neighbors affect the outcome of $y$.

$$ y = \rho W y + \beta x + \gamma W_1 x_1$$

Note that this is different from the Spatial Durbin Model,

$$ y = \rho W y + X\beta + WX\gamma$$

in that only a specific attribute is receiving a spatial lag --- not all of the attributes --- and also that the neighbors relationship might be different from the relationship on $y$.

Is such a model possible to estimate? It appears that the `spdep` package for R doesn't do this, but are there ways around it?

Comment: It isn't different than the Spatial Durbin model (just a special case). Since $x_1$ is exogenous you can just calculate the spatial lag and insert it on the right hand side of the model. $W$ can be whatever you want it to be. $W$ that is not row normalized is sometimes easier to interpret and calculate marginal effects.